# Use GPO or similar to shut all network instances of Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, gpo

Is there a way that GPO or similar can be used to distribute a command to all workstations on a domain at say, 1am, which will shut down all instances of Internet Explorer on those workstations which are left on overnight?  Workstations are all thick clients.

Comment: Hi, I have seen managed public access computers that use a batch task to close all open IE windows when the screen saver starts.

Answer (score 0):

[kioskstart.vbs]

```
'SCRIPT purpose: Reset IE into Kiosk mode once Screensaver comes on.
'UPDATED: 02/06/18



OPTION EXPLICIT
DIM strComputer,strProcess,strProcess2, restartFlag
DIM oshell : set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strComputer = "." ' local computer
strProcess = "SnapSCR.scr"
restartFlag = true

DO While true
    IF isProcessRunning(strComputer,strProcess) THEN
        IF restartFlag = true THEN
            oShell.Run "taskkill /im iexplore.exe",, True
            oShell.Run "iexplore.exe -k",,True
            restartFlag = false
        ELSE    
            restartFlag = false
        End if
    ELSE 
        restartFlag = true
    END IF
    WScript.Sleep 10000
LOOP


' Function to check if a process is running
FUNCTION isProcessRunning(BYVAL strComputer,BYVAL strProcessName)

    DIM objWMIService, strWMIQuery

    strWMIQuery = "Select * from Win32_Process where name like '" & strProcessName & "'"

    SET objWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
            & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 



IF objWMIService.ExecQuery(strWMIQuery).Count > 0 THEN
        isProcessRunning = TRUE
    ELSE
        isProcessRunning = FALSE
END IF


END FUNCTION
```